# Parameters causing query to slow down

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parameters

I have this query

```
DECLARE @Company VARCHAR(20) = 'ABC'
DECLARE @Train INT = 1

SELECT L.*
FROM vemd_episodes_firstnet_currentPatients L 
INNER JOIN vemd_episodes E ON E.Company = L.Company 
                           AND E.cpid = L.cpid  
                           AND E.dDate = L.dDate
WHERE L.Company = @Company
  AND ((census_datetime NOT IN (SELECT MAX(census_datetime) FROM vemd_episodes_firstnet_currentPatients ) AND @Train = 1)
       OR (census_datetime IN (SELECT MAX(census_datetime) FROM vemd_episodes_firstnet_currentPatients ) AND @Train = 0))
```

It takes forever to finish.

After 1 minute it only retrieve 400 records and is still running.

Total number of records this query should fetch is around 500,000 records.

[image]

But when I hard code the parameters in the query

```
SELECT L.*
FROM vemd_episodes_firstnet_currentPatients L 
INNER JOIN vemd_episodes E ON E.Company = L.Company 
                           AND E.cpid = L.cpid  
                           AND E.dDate = L.dDate
WHERE L.Company = 'ABC'
  AND ((census_datetime NOT IN (SELECT MAX(census_datetime) FROM vemd_episodes_firstnet_currentPatients ) AND 1 = 1)
       OR (census_datetime IN (SELECT MAX(census_datetime) FROM vemd_episodes_firstnet_currentPatients ) AND 1 = 0))
```

it is extremely fast and retrieves 500k records in 16 seconds.

Why is using parameters in the `where` clause causing this issue? And how to fix it?

***Edit :***

I could not keep it running till the end

so I select top 1000 and got execution plan

[image]

Comment: Are you executing both the queries against the same database from the same location?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes , same everything

Comment: Can you please share both query execution plans?

Comment: @El.Hum I cannot,  the query has not finished running, it may take long hours to finish, to get execution plan the query should run till the end

Comment: @El.Hum I have edited the question plz have a look at the execution plan

Comment: Usually the set operators like IN, NOT IN, UNION, etc will have high impact on the query performance and they should be avoided as much as possible. Since you are taking only the max value within the sub-query, so why are you using IN?

Comment: Why is it using `IN` but with a query that only returns a single value?

Comment: What is the performance like when you use ```L.Company = @Company``` and keep the remaining hard-coded parameter values in play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the query with the recompile option `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`
With parameterized queries, SQL sometimes chooses the wrong execution plan and insist to use it.

```
DECLARE @Company VARCHAR(20) = 'ABC'
DECLARE @Train INT = 1

SELECT L.*
FROM vemd_episodes_firstnet_currentPatients L 
INNER JOIN vemd_episodes E ON E.Company = L.Company 
                           AND E.cpid = L.cpid  
                           AND E.dDate = L.dDate
WHERE L.Company = @Company
  AND ((census_datetime NOT IN (SELECT MAX(census_datetime) FROM vemd_episodes_firstnet_currentPatients ) AND @Train = 1)
       OR (census_datetime IN (SELECT MAX(census_datetime) FROM vemd_episodes_firstnet_currentPatients ) AND @Train = 0))
OPTION  (RECOMPILE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using window functions:

```
SELECT L.*
FROM (SELECT L.*,
             MAX(census_datetime) OVER () as max_census_datetime
      FROM vemd_episodes_firstnet_currentPatients L 
     ) L JOIN
     vemd_episodes E
     ON E.Company = L.Company AND
        E.cpid = L.cpid AND
        E.dDate = L.dDate
WHERE L.Company = @Company AND
      ((census_datetime <> max_census_datetime AND @Train = 1) OR
       (census_datetime = max_census_datetime AND @Train = 0)
      );
```

The optimizer should find it easier to generate an appropriate execution plan with a simpler `where` clause.